# Scala fold evaluate function ifEmpty instead of expression

Tags: scala, option-type, fold

If I have an `Option`:

```
val o = someFuncReturningOption()
```

and I chose to `fold`:

```
o.fold(valIfEmpty){(_, i) => println(i) }
```

Is there a variant of `fold` or another function that takes a function instead of a value for `ifEmpty` such that the function is only evaluated if the (in this case) `Option` is empty, instead of taking a value?

**Edit**: the `ifEmpty` function takes arguments.

Comment: In Scala 2.11.x it is call by name: `@inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B =` so it is evaluated only if it is empty. Which version do you use?

Comment: 2.11.6. I neglected to mention I have arguments for the `ifEmpty` function.

Comment: *2.11.5, sorry. Post updated.

Comment: Is your problem that the `ifEmpty` function arguments get evaluated? In that case write a wrapper/modify it to make those parameters also call-by-name (`=>`).

Comment: @atc Could you please provide troubled example and desired behavior, so we haven't to guess them?

Comment: All the information is there, Odomontois. Andrzej seems to get it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See output (scala 2.11):

```scala
scala> def func = { println("Evaluate if empty"); (3,4)}
func: (Int, Int)

scala> val opt = Option((4,5))
opt: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((4,5))

scala> opt.fold(func)( x => x)
res7: (Int, Int) = (4,5)

scala> opt.getOrElse(func)
res8: (Int, Int) = (4,5)

scala> val none:Option[(Int,Int)] = None 
none: Option[(Int, Int)] = None

scala> none.getOrElse(func)
Evaluate if empty
res9: (Int, Int) = (3,4)

scala> none.fold(func)(x => x)
Evaluate if empty
res10: (Int, Int) = (3,4)
```

func is called only if Option is None

**Edit**
If ifEmpty takes the arguments, the behavior is the same:

```scala
scala> def funcWithArguments(default:(Int,Int)) = { println("Evaluate if empty"); default}
funcWithArguments: (default: (Int, Int))(Int, Int)

scala> opt.getOrElse(func((2,4)))
res4: (Int, Int) = (4,5)

scala>  none.getOrElse(func((2,4)))
Evaluate if empty
res5: (Int, Int) = (2,4)
```

See signature of method getOrElse:

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

The expression is evaluated only, when is called (when Option is empty)

If you need to transform result type, use the construction with map:

```
scala> none.map(a => a._2).getOrElse({println("ifEmpty");8})
ifEmpty
res13: Int = 8

scala> opt.map(a => a._2).getOrElse({println("ifEmpty");8})
res14: Int = 5
```

Comment: And what if the function for `ifEmpty` takes arguments?

Comment: `opt.fold(func)( x => x)` is equivalent to `opt.fold(func)(identity)`